# Sending MOV file over TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I want send transfer mov file over TCP Client/server. How I should know where file ends? When I send XML file it was easy, search null in incoming byte[] cut, save it, THERE XML file ready. What about MOV file?

Answer (score 0):

A more general form of your question, how to determine the end of any TCP "packet", has a few different solutions. Your first way was to search for a null terminator. I'd say a better way is to prefix your stream with an `int` representing the length of the .MOV file. Then you know exactly how many bytes to read.

Answer (score 0):

Send file size first, then contents.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways. The easiest one (but a bit error-prone) - close your connection after you finish sending the file. The receiver will know the connection is shutdown, and will understand the file is done.

The drawback of this technique, is that if the connection is broken, the receiver might detect this as an end-of-file, and you'll end up with a partial file.

The second way is to send the file length first, then the file.